# Como leer archivo de configuracion(cfg) Django

Tags: python, django

Saludos tengo un archivo de configuracion para un proyecto de Django con la siguiente estructura(settings.cfg):

```
[server]
host = "localhost"
user = "root"
pwd = "toor"
```

dentro de mi archivo "**settings.py**" intento obtener la configuración de la siguiente manera:

```
import ConfigParser
configParser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()   
configFilePath = 'settings.cfg'
configParser.read(configFilePath)
print configParser.get('server', 'host')
```

a lo cual me genera el siguiente error:

```
[roo@rgmanagement_2 facturacion]$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 302, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/var/www/html/facturacion/inventarios/settings.py", line 9, in <module>
    print configParser.get('server', 'host')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 330, in get
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'server'
```

Quizá alguna sugerencia de como puedo leer este archivo y usarlo para configurar parámetros de settings.py, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te está leyendo tu archivo `settings.cfg`. Debes de indicar la ruta correctamente.

Prueba insertando `/` en `configFilePath`:

```
import ConfigParser
configParser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()   
configFilePath = '/settings.cfg'
configParser.read(configFilePath)
print configParser.get('server', 'host')
```

En caso de que tampoco te funcione prueba metiendo la ruta absoluta:

```
import ConfigParser
configParser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()   
configFilePath = r'C:/ruta/settings.cfg'
configParser.read(configFilePath)
print configParser.get('server', 'host')
```

Pero ya te digo, el problema es esa variable, que no encuentra el fichero.